# What are some alternative for ModelChoiceField for large number of choices?

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu, django-forms, html-select

According to [#17950](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17950) about [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) which allows the selection of a single model object, suitable for representing a foreign key.

> Note that the default widget for ModelChoiceField becomes impractical when the number of entries increases. You should avoid using it for more than 100 items.

This is pretty obvious because selecting 100 choices from **Select** box is not easy. One have to scroll down or find the option.

What are some possible solution if there are a lot of options?

---

### Solution 1

Still use the `ModelChoiceField` but with customized widget such as [*select2*](https://github.com/asyncee/django-easy-select2), [*chosen*](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), [*react-select*](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/), etc... instead of `Select` widget. It may help with the filter of the choices. The choices will be queried at asynchronously to separate API endpoint when the user type the input of the select box.

### Solution 2

Primitive, is to provide a blank `CharField` with a `TextInput` Widget. Thus the user will have to enter the value manually.

### Solution 3

Solution 2 can be further improved by providing a popup window that list down all the choices. User can search the choices, and upon clicking the choices the window will close and the form will be populated with the values automatically. The popup is very similar to django admin list. (Checkout Grappelli [RelatedLookup](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#related-lookups) to know more what I mean, see image below)

[image]

---

Would there be any other solutions please share? and why that solution better?

Comment: Something pure frontend: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @ShangWang thanks for the suggestion, that's very similar to select2 alternative. I've just added it into the solution1 choices.

Comment: My point is that you might not need anything asynchronously. Do you have so many choices that the page starts to load slowly? If not then I don't know why you hesitate to choose one of those pure front end implementations to just make the UX easier to use.

Comment: Normally that's what happen with ModelChoiceField, because the choices is from a particular model, the queryset result may reach more than 10000 of choices. And we wouldn't load entire choices during the view render because it is a lot.

Comment: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score -1):

I have used in my UX a previous page with the list of options where it is possible to search and paginate the data then the user selects an item from the list to be redirected to another page where it has a hidden field in the form filled with the item selected in the previous list .

Comment: Where is your effort.